# Chart.js Update Dataset by Axis ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, chart.js

I have one x-axis and two y-axis data. I declare my datasets as follows:

```
chart.data.datasets.push({
    yAxisID: "ID1",
    label: "Label1"
});

chart.data.datasets.push({
    yAxisID: "ID2",
    label: "Label2"
});
```

How do I update my dataset by ID and  not by index? Something like `chart.data.datasets[yAxisID = "Label1"].data.push({});`.

So far I can append data by index similar to below:

```
chart.data.datasets[0].data.push({
    x: 4,
    y: 6.5
});
```

Comment: Can you explain why you want to be able to do that? An axis can have multiple datasets so you'd still need to know the dataset index.

Comment: @timclutton i’m actually using chart.js streaming with the intention to continuously update the chart over a period of time. My data values come from a data source that feeds me data continuosly. This service only gives me the ID and the corresponding value. Every time I get data from the service, I want to push it to the chart.